# What is the most efficient algorithm to Insert an element in a ordered simple list

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Which one is the best algorithm to insert a new element in a ordered list?
Supose that I a have the list [1,3,8,10,14,20] and I'd like to insert the element 9.

I'm not talking about a programming language but about the most efficient algorithm to do that.

Tks

ps.: I'm not sure if the insert sort is the best one.

Comment: List or array? These are different things.

Comment: @Henry list. I edited. Tks

Comment: Well, you can use a doubly linked list. This way you won't have to shift elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To insert a single element, you traverse the list from the front until you find the insertion point and then insert the new element (by pointer manipulations).

If you need to insert many elements and the list does not necessarily have to be sorted all the time it may be better to insert the new elements in the front and then do a final sort.

Answer (score 1):

Inserting a new element will take approximately the same time no matter the algorithm if its an array. To explain it better:

You will always need a `O(n)` complexity part in the algorithm to shift the array elements that come after the inserted element to make space where you can put that element.

Your best bet would be to decrease the search complexity, and the best way is to use binary search, which has a complexity of `O(log n)`.

With this your insert has a complexity of `(n + log n)`, which is the same as `O(n)`.

**To increase efficiency, you need to pick a better data structure, that has constant insert time like a binary search tree or a some sort of heap.**

Comment: The question is about a list, but apart from that the complexity of binary search is not needed. One can combine shifting up with the search.

Comment: If it's a list, then you are right. Also, in that case, we cant use binary search. But I still stand by the bold part.